# Angular 4 search in two lists

Tags: angular

I have started to develop a new app,trying to use angular in my app,however I am new and I need some orientation.

```
 <form id="filter">
   <label>Searching for tel.no</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="term" />
    </form>

    <ul *ngFor="let hero of listA |filter:term">  
    <div class="single-hero">
    {{hero.price}}
    </div>
    </ul>
```

filter.pipe

```
if(term===undefined) return listA;
    return listA.filter(function(hero){
        return hero.prefix.includes(term));
    })
```

Currently it gives me term is not defined

```
export class AppComponent {
li = []; lu=[]
```

Help would be appriciated

Comment: What are you trying to do? to be exact. and how does your data look?

Comment: would you please provide your full component code and full pipe?

Comment: @RayLuxembourg { prefix :11, price: 20 },I am trying to have a search that searches in two lists

Comment: @AnasAlHamdan  Component({ selector: 'app-root', templateUrl: './app.component.html', styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'], pipes:[FilterPipe] })

Comment: @ElizabethD. hmmm did you check inside pipe that it receives the data correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexOF

```
export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any[], term: any[]): any {
      if (!term) 
        return items;
      return items.filter(item => item.prefix.indexOf(term) > -1);
    }
}
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/u5tNoZ38AdPCGWrbWJG6?p=preview)**

Comment: this removes the error but what else should I change in my app.component?

Comment: I made your modifications but why cant I see the output?

Comment: compare the demo and see what you are missing

Comment: I just did and its exactly as the demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVTNaYBVP88

Comment: after making the |filter:1 ,it gives me this errorhero.prefix.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Check if prefix is an array

Comment: prefix is part of my hero class type number,I removed it and changed it but still no display,hero.indexOf is not a function

Comment: it works that good , helped me to uderstand that term will work